# Copy style of layer/symbology from Copernicus

Tags: qgis, raster, style, copernicus, soil

I am looking for simple solution to what I believe is a possibility of QGIS that is unknown to me as a rookie in the field.

Simply put, I would like to copy the style of the following soil pH map from Copernicus - https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/content/soil-ph-europe .

After downloading the .shp and all associated files, how do I get to the styling of the raster that is presented here https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/public_path/ph2.png

? After adding the .adf file, we get the usual single-band grey symbology but this is not wanted, and I know how to change it to pseudocolour and etc., but I want the exact same symbology as in the latter.

Is it in some of the files or do can I use some color ramp website or do I have to do it completely "manually"?

Comment: a shapefile is not a raster

Comment: My mistake, but the question still stands.